# android app is not sending value to web service

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask

My webservicecall.java file which contains code to call server

```
  public class WebserviceCall {

/**
 * Variable Decleration................
 *
 */
String namespace = "http://bkagartala.technotripura.com/";
private String url = "http://bkagartala.technotripura.com/asha/WebService.asmx";

String SOAP_ACTION;
SoapObject request = null, objMessages = null;
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport;
WebserviceCall() {
}


/**
 * Set Envelope
 */
protected void SetEnvelope() {

    try {

        // Creating SOAP envelope
        envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        //You can comment that line if your web service is not .NET one.
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
         androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Soap Exception---->>>" + e.toString());
    }
}

// MethodName variable is define for which webservice function  will call
public String getchange_liveserver(String MethodName, String f_name)
{

    try {
        SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/"+MethodName;

        //Adding values to request object
        request = new SoapObject(namespace, MethodName);

        //Adding Double value to request object
        PropertyInfo weightProp =new PropertyInfo();
        weightProp.setName("f_name");
        weightProp.setValue(f_name);

        weightProp.setType(String.class);

         request.addProperty(weightProp);

        //Adding String value to request object

        SetEnvelope();

        try {

            //SOAP calling webservice
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            //Got Webservice response
            String result = envelope.getResponse().toString();

            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            return e.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        return e.toString();
    }

   }


/************************************/
 }
```

called that web service class to another activity in asynctask

```
      aResponse = com.getchange_liveserver("soumya", "one");
```

but the main problem app is not sending that value to server....

web service code

```
 Imports System.Web
  Imports System.Web.Services
   Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols



  <WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
 <WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
 <Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
  Public Class WebService
 Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function HelloWorld() As String
    Return "Hello World"
End Function
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function soumya(ByVal f_name As String) As String


    Dim a As String = f_name


    If a = "one" Then
        a = "hello"
        Return a

    ElseIf a = "two" Then
        a = "may"
        Return a
    Else
        a = "do"
        Return a


    End If
End Function

   End Class
```

Comment: post your error or exception you are getting

Comment: m not getting any error just not getting the desired output.

Comment: it should give me "hello"

Comment: problem is  it is sending null value to web service

Answer (score 0):

Change your Namespace to tempuri.org i guess that is the problem...i have given simple example try it and replace according to you values...

I guess the problem is with your NAMESPACE i can see tempuri.org in you service file

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
            String METHOD_NAME = "Your Method Name";
            String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE+METHOD_NAME;
            String URL = "http://bkagartala.technotripura.com/asha/WebService.asmx";
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            request.addProperty("methodName", METHOD_NAME);

            request.addProperty("ModelNumber", VariableName You Want to Pass);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

            envelope.dotNet = true;

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I/AndroidExampleOutput: ----java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: at which line?..also its good to have errors then no errors...you can atleast correct them ;)

Comment: request = new SoapObject(namespace, MethodName);

            //Adding Double value to request object
            PropertyInfo weightProp =new PropertyInfo();
            weightProp.setName("f_name");
            weightProp.setValue(f_name);

            weightProp.setType(String.class);

             request.addProperty(weightProp);

Comment: don't add double value then...use String.valueOf(variable having double value) also change accepting type of that variable in your sevice file

Comment: tried this way...  request.addProperty("methodName", "soumya");

            request.addProperty("f_name", f_name);
but same nullpointer exception

Comment: there is only string value

Comment: bro post the line at which you are getting that exception...and post the exception also

Comment: try {

                //SOAP calling webservice
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                //Got Webservice response
                String result = envelope.getResponse().toString();

                return result;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                return (e.toString());

Comment: I/AndroidExampleOutput: ----java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: Okay i got it...the error is your SoapSerialisationEnvelope is not getting initialised...forget your code for a second and put your variable inside my code and it will work

Comment: atleast it is returning something...now check your webservice code ...see if any conditions are getting satisfied.. otherwise it will return null only

Comment: String aResponse="nul";

Comment: SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                aResponse= response.toString();

Comment: how to get that string output returned by web service?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive.toString()' on a null object reference